# Maven exclude dependency of transitive dependency

Tags: dependencies, maven-3, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

I have this dependency tree: `A->B->C->D`. `A` is the main project. I would like to know if it’s possible to exclude only `D` from `A` without needing to add explicitly `C` to `A`? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer following maven documentation which contains an example and covers your use case:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

**Following is example snapshot for quick reference:**

[image]